# Scrapy: Extract value from meta tag

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm building a crawler for a webpage that for some reason decided to hold ID numbers for the items I'm extracting in meta tags as such

```
<meta content="1001662613">
```

where the number in quotation marks is the number I want.

I tried using the xpath

```
Id = title.select('//meta [@content]').extract()
```

But results for that come out empty. Using

```
Id = title.select('//meta/@content').extract()
```

in turn give me the entire page's source code after the meta tag...

Is there any way to extract the number from the tag itelf, instead of trying to go into the tag (which is empty)?

For reference, here's an example of the section of the page's source where the ID number is located

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ccss/2076d1c6bea75c5b6f4c753b3b4920b6_14bfe2d5b91d791bc05282634acdfb68.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/cjs/986570aebf4e6cef6e0a52faa9c5a8a2_f4ceae6565fa007f39ee4e0abe02ab7b.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/cjs/a373b58f85b5e68c60f3edc35b348e14_a2abaa7837c3e1ccda94d6fe6b0f7a8f.js"></script>
<meta content="1001657519"/>
<link href="http://www.groupon.com.uy/descuentos/montevideo/sushi-go-26-12-7" rel="canonical" />
<link href="http://www.groupon.com.uy/deals/feed.rss" type="application/rss+xml" rel="alternate" title="Groupon - Descuentos" />
<meta name="title" content="Desde $264 en vez de $462 por 24, 48 o 72 piezas de sushi en Sushi Go"/>
```

Comment: Could you try `/html/head/meta/@content`?

Comment: Same as using //meta/@content. Gives me about 6 lines of results, not just the number I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`//meta/@content` returns multiple results because of multiple `meta` tags on the page. Just filter the one that contains digits:

```
ids = title.select('//meta/@content').extract()
print [id for id in ids if id.isdigit()]
```

Hoep that helps.

Comment: This works, but there are more than one digit caught by this and the first one it gives is not the one I need. Is there any way to tell it to get the second, or nth "next" id? I'm not familiar with iterators in Python, sorry...

Comment: @ConnorU sure, I've edited the answer. It should prints both of them using list comprehension. Just take the one you need.

Comment: I figured out I just had to unstack the for and then the if. There are only two numbers in the meta content tags, so I just do for id in ids: if id.isdigit():Id=id  [[not the best or most elegant way but it works and it only runs one extra assignment call so efficiency impact is low]. Thanks!

Comment: @ConnorU glad to hear that. FYI, if there is any difference between these `meta` tags with digits - you can use the difference to distinguish them: e.g. may be the one has some attribute that another one doesn't, or may be they are located in different "containers"..